# What's alternative of eval function?

Tags: php, eval

I use `eval()` in my current project like this:

```
if (class_exists($class_name)) //$class_name depends on user input
    eval($class_name.'::MyStaticMethod()');
```

`eval()` is executed if and only if class with the name `$class_name` exists so it's kinda safe, but I still don't think that this is the best solution.

Can I do the same what code above does without `eval()`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*I have recently answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672183/php-eval-does-not-return-the-function-results). The last part of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17672269/1283847) perfectly answers this question and is much more useful for future readers than answers provided here. That's why I am answering my own question.*

PHP has features that gives possibility to avoid using `eval` in most cases:

1. PHP is very dynamic language. It has ability to do following stuff with [`strings`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

   - Define and/or get variable (supported from PHP 4.3). For example:

     ```
     $variableName = 'MyVariable';
     // Create new variable with the name defined in variable $variableName
     ${$variableName} = 'MyValue';
     //Outputs: string(7) "MyValue"
     var_dump($MyVariable);
     //Outputs: string(7) "MyValue"
     var_dump(${'MyVariable'});
     ```

     [Demo](http://3v4l.org/AQ5I3)
   - Call function (supported from PHP 4.3). For example:

     ```
     // Create function with the name defined in variable $functionName
     function MyFunction($argument) {
         return 'Argument passed is: '.$argument;
     }

     $functionName = 'MyFunction';

     // Outputs:
     // string(48) "Argument passed is: Calling MyFunction directly."
     var_dump(MyFunction('Calling MyFunction directly.'));
     // Outputs:
     // string(51) "Argument passed is: Calling MyFunction with string."
     var_dump($functionName('Calling MyFunction with string.'));
     ```

     [Demo](http://3v4l.org/lPDRH)
   - Create instance of class (supported from PHP 5.0). For example:

     ```
     class MyClass {
         public function __construct() {
             echo 'Constructing MyClass'."\n";
         }
     }

     $className = 'MyClass';

     $objFromString = new $className();
     // Outputs: object(MyClass)#1 (0) {}
     var_dump($objFromString);
     ```

     [Demo](http://3v4l.org/dkqP0)
   - Call static method (supported from PHP 5.0). For example:

     ```
     class MyClass {
         public static function staticMethod() {
             return 'MyClass::staticMethod called';
         }
     }

     $staticMethodName = 'staticMethod';
     // Outputs: string(28) "MyClass::staticMethod called"
     var_dump(MyClass::$staticMethodName());
     ```

     [Demo](http://3v4l.org/rApQn)

     And from PHP 5.3 class name can also be defined by string. Example:

     ```
     class MyClass {
         public static function staticMethod() {
         return 'MyClass::staticMethod called';
         }
     }

     $className = 'MyClass';
     $staticMethodName = 'staticMethod';

     var_dump($className::$staticMethodName());
     var_dump($className::staticMethod());
     ```

     [Demo](http://3v4l.org/TCnSr)
   - Call instance method of object (supported from PHP 5.0). For example:

     ```
     class MyClass {
         public function instanceMethod() {
             return 'MyClass::instanceMethod called';
         }
     }

     $methodName = 'instanceMethod';

     $obj = new MyClass();
     // Outputs: string(30) "MyClass::instanceMethod called"
     var_dump($obj->$methodName());
     ```

     [Demo](http://3v4l.org/eiLdL)
   - Access static and instance properties of object (supported from PHP 5.0). For example:

     ```
     class MyClass {
         public static $myStaticProperty;
         public $myInstanceProperty;
     }

     $staticPropertyName = 'myStaticProperty';
     $instancePropertyName = 'myInstanceProperty';

     MyClass::${$staticPropertyName} = 'my static value';
     $obj = new MyClass();
     $obj->{$instancePropertyName} = 'my instance value';

     var_dump(MyClass::${$staticPropertyName});
     var_dump($obj->{$instancePropertyName});
     ```

     [Demo](http://3v4l.org/njit9)
2. PHP has two functions: [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) and [`call_user_func_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) for dynamic function/method calls. Both are perfectly documented so I won't go in details here.
3. Even if everything above is not enough PHP 5 comes with great [`Reflection` API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php). Unfortunately, documentation has few examples but reflection is quite large topic to cover here. Basically, It's not a big deal to use reflection after reading how it works.

Comment: All of this information (dynamic access to variable/functions and instance/static members) is pretty common knowledge and part of the PHP docs. Aggregating it all here as an answer isn't particularly useful without changing the question itself from "what's alternative of eval" to "what dynamic access does PHP offer".

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.call-user-func.php.).

An alternative to `call_user_func()` would be calling it like this:

```
$class_and_method = 'Class::MyStaticMethod()';
$class_and_method();
```

Answer (score 5):

yes:

```
call_user_func(array($class_name, 'MyStaticMethod'));
```

Answer (score 3):

As of PHP 5.3+,

```
$class_name::MyStaticMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

Adisory:
userinput + eval = security hole;

Also eval is an expensive operation requiring parsing the string into an actionable format (parse tree, abstract syntax tree, etc.) and executing the new found logic.

You don't want to eval every little tidbit of code. Use eval if you have something for it to chew on or rather put that logic somewhere where it's reusable and parametrized such as a function.

Also as of php 5.4

```
$method = array('class_name', 'method_name');
$method(); // calls class_name::method_name()
```

Answer (score 1):

To evaluate some PHP code after the load.

We can use `proc_open` and feed some PHP into the `STDIN`.

To avoid any issues with the shell and Unicode characters, it's safer to pass in a String encoded in `base64`.

Note that PHP depends then from the php-cli .ini settings.

```
function run($php){
  $php = base64_encode($php);
  $proc = proc_open("echo '$php' | base64 --decode | php",
    [["pipe","r"],["pipe","w"],["pipe","w"]],
    $pipes
  );
  print stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
}

run("Hi <?php echo getenv()['USER'];?>! \n");
// Hi NVRM!
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php