# eval() does not return the function results

Tags: php, eval

I have a method name that is stored in a column in the DB that looks like this:

```
customs::nicknames($data)
```

This is the related class:

```
    class customs extends service {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public static function nicknames($data) {
        return $data;
    }

}
```

When I call it in this way:

```
$merge = eval($error['custom'] . ';');
```

The contents of the $data variable is not returned.
Just to give it a try I tried with `echo` and it is correctly returning the array to string conversion php error.
So the variable `$data` is read correctly. But why does not it return anything?

If I try to call this method without using `eval()` like this:

```
$merge = customs::nicknames($data);
```

The `$data` is returned correctly.

So what's wrong?

Why `eval()` is not able to return the method results? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried eval('return ' . $error['custom'] . ';'); ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> #### Why *eval()* is not able to return the method results?

Simply because you don't return anything in your [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) part.

> [*Docs:*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)
>
> ***eval()*** returns `NULL` unless ***return*** is called in the evaluated code, in which case the value passed to ***return*** is returned.

---

> #### How can I solve this issue?

You can assign variable (`$merge` in given example) in [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). For example:

```
eval('$merge =' . $error['custom'] . ';');
```

or [`return`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) value in [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). E.g:

```
$merge = eval('return '.$error['custom'].';');
```

---

**Note:** Don't use [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) in real-world applications.

> [*Warning from docs:*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)
>
> The ***eval()*** language construct is ***very dangerous*** because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. ***Its use thus is
>   discouraged.*** If you have carefully verified that there is no other
>   option than to use this construct, pay special attention ***not to pass
>   any user provided data*** into it without properly validating it
>   beforehand.

---

> #### If *eval()* is dangerous is there another way to read a string as code in a safe way?

Yes, there is (actually, are):

1. PHP is very dynamic language. It has ability to do following stuff with [`strings`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

   - Define and/or get variable (supported from PHP 4.3). For example:

     ```
     $variableName = 'MyVariable';
     // Create new variable with the name defined in variable $variableName
     ${$variableName} = 'MyValue';
     //Outputs: string(7) "MyValue"
     var_dump($MyVariable);
     //Outputs: string(7) "MyValue"
     var_dump(${'MyVariable'});
     ```

     [Demo](http://3v4l.org/AQ5I3)
   - Call function (supported from PHP 4.3). For example:

     ```
     // Create function with the name defined in variable $functionName
     function MyFunction($argument) {
         return 'Argument passed is: '.$argument;
     }

     $functionName = 'MyFunction';

     // Outputs:
     // string(48) "Argument passed is: Calling MyFunction directly."
     var_dump(MyFunction('Calling MyFunction directly.'));
     // Outputs:
     // string(51) "Argument passed is: Calling MyFunction with string."
     var_dump($functionName('Calling MyFunction with string.'));
     ```

     [Demo](http://3v4l.org/lPDRH)
   - Create instance of class (supported from PHP 5.0). For example:

     ```
     class MyClass {
         public function __construct() {
             echo 'Constructing MyClass'."\n";
         }
     }

     $className = 'MyClass';

     $objFromString = new $className();
     // Outputs: object(MyClass)#1 (0) {}
     var_dump($objFromString);
     ```

     [Demo](http://3v4l.org/dkqP0)
   - Call static method (supported from PHP 5.0). For example:

     ```
     class MyClass {
         public static function staticMethod() {
             return 'MyClass::staticMethod called';
         }
     }

     $staticMethodName = 'staticMethod';
     // Outputs: string(28) "MyClass::staticMethod called"
     var_dump(MyClass::$staticMethodName());
     ```

     [Demo](http://3v4l.org/rApQn)

     And from PHP 5.3 class name can also be defined by string. Example:

     ```
     class MyClass {
         public static function staticMethod() {
         return 'MyClass::staticMethod called';
         }
     }

     $className = 'MyClass';
     $staticMethodName = 'staticMethod';

     var_dump($className::$staticMethodName());
     var_dump($className::staticMethod());
     ```

     [Demo](http://3v4l.org/TCnSr)
   - Call instance method of object (supported from PHP 5.0). For example:

     ```
     class MyClass {
         public function instanceMethod() {
             return 'MyClass::instanceMethod called';
         }
     }

     $methodName = 'instanceMethod';

     $obj = new MyClass();
     // Outputs: string(30) "MyClass::instanceMethod called"
     var_dump($obj->$methodName());
     ```

     [Demo](http://3v4l.org/eiLdL)
   - Access static and instance properties of object (supported from PHP 5.0). For example:

     ```
     class MyClass {
         public static $myStaticProperty;
         public $myInstanceProperty;
     }

     $staticPropertyName = 'myStaticProperty';
     $instancePropertyName = 'myInstanceProperty';

     MyClass::${$staticPropertyName} = 'my static value';
     $obj = new MyClass();
     $obj->{$instancePropertyName} = 'my instance value';

     var_dump(MyClass::${$staticPropertyName});
     var_dump($obj->{$instancePropertyName});
     ```

     [Demo](http://3v4l.org/njit9)
2. PHP has two functions: [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) and [`call_user_func_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) for dynamic function/method calls. Both are perfectly documented so I won't go in details here.
3. Even if everything above is not enough PHP 5 comes with great [`Reflection` API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php). Unfortunately, documentation has few examples but reflection is quite large topic to cover here. Basically, It's not a big deal to use reflection after reading how it works.

Comment: If eval() is dangerous is there another way to read a string as code in a safe way? This is for a private API system so I am not worried. But in the future I may need it

Comment: @DiegoPucci I have updated my answer with alternatives. Also it does not matter if it's private or not. According to Murphy's lay: [_Anything that can go wrong, will go wrong_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy's_law).

Comment: @DiegoPucci I've edited answer. I think you'd be interested in rereading one.