# Write textarea value as PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am creating a WordPress plugin where a user can specify a custom loop repeater based on the value of a textarea.

The idea is, a user can use a predefined repeater that ships with the plugin or they can build their own repeater by simply adding html + PHP to the textarea.

*Example of a custom repeater:*

```
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1> <?php the_excerpt(); ?> - <?php the_time(); ?>
```

The issue is when I echo/print the textarea value, the WordPress functions within the `<?php ?>` tags do not execute.

Is what I'm attempting even possible?

---

Let me explain further... 
I am building an installable plugin based on my [Ajax Load More](https://github.com/dcooney/wordpress-ajax-load-more) script. 
This plugin will be only used by site admins and for total control of the display of posts I want to allow them to create a [custom repeater](https://github.com/dcooney/wordpress-ajax-load-more/blob/master/ajax-load-more/includes/repeater-list.php).

On the plugin settings page, I want to have a textarea where the admins can add whatever html/php code they want in order to customize the repeater.

My issue is how do I execute the PHP entered within the textarea on the frontend as echoing the value does not work.

Comment: can you clarify, are you trying to allow them to execute PHP in the wordpress page content area?

Comment: you do **NOT** want to allow your users to enter arbitrary php code into your site. e.g. consider `<?php system('rm -rf /'); echo 'tee hee!; ?>`

Comment: Yeah, if you just *print* text, you're just printing text. It doesn't matter what that text contains...

Comment: Yes, essentially I want to echo the value of a textarea (saved via plugin settings) on the frontend within a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Use `eval` function to change plain text to php code. More about it [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

```
eval('echo "Hello world!"');
```

will print out "Hello world!" instead of 'echo "Hello world!"'

**BUT** what if i write to textarea:

```
die();
```

Comment: `eval` can be quite dangerous. However, there are other ways to get to the same goal, as leri explaned here quite lengthy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672183/eval-does-not-return-the-function-results/17672269#17672269

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is to use the `eval()` function as Justinas says, but I would strongly recommend you don't use it as I have found it to be unreliable and problematic.

What I would recommend is to write the PHP code in the string you extract from the text area to a file and then include that file where you want the PHP to execute.

So, I would recommend running

```
<?php file_put_contents($file_path, $contents); ?>
```

whenever the text area is updated to update the file, then

```
<?php include_once($file_path); ?>
```

where you want the code on the front end.

Comment: thanks. This is exactly the approach I have taken. Works perfectly once written to a php file and then included in the loop.

Answer (score -1):

Those wordpress functions will not work unless they are in the Loop, Here is a basic Loop:

```
 <?php if(have_posts()) { ?>    
 <?php while(have_posts()) { ?> 
 <?php the_post(); ?>   
 <?php // custom post content code for title, excerpt and featured image ?> 
 <?php } // end while ?>    
 <?php } // end if ?>
```

Comment: Issue is not the loop. The issue is executing PHP saved within a textbox inside the loop.