# How can I construct log messages in a DRY fashion?

Tags: php, oop, events

I am using an event manager to raise events that need to be logged (it's Phalcon's event manager, but it isn't really important for this question). Phalcon's event manager allows you to register a listener to events raised by another object. Whenever event `a` happens, Phalcon's event manager calls `Listener::a()`.

The reason I'm using events is that I don't want my business logic to be cluttered with log statements.

So, for my example scenario, let's imagine that you have a `UserService` object which has methods like `signUp()`, `signIn()`, `grantPermission()`, `revokePermission()`, and so on. Each of these raise an event which has its own data, meaning that I need different data to construct the log message, so different stuff are being passed. For example, my signUpSuccessful log message is "User #4 created.". For creating this message, I need the user's id, so my `UserService` will do:

```
$eventManager->fire('signUpSuccessful', $this, $user);
```

And my listener will have:

```
public function signUpSuccessful($event, $source, $data)
{
    $this->logger->log(Logger::info, 'User #' . $data->getId() . ' created.');
}
```

Now, as you can imagine, if I continue the trend, this class will contain a lot of functions that do nothing but use a property of `$data` to construct a log message.

How can I construct the messages without creating lots of functions? Is there a design pattern for this? I've thought of overriding `__call()`, but that would mean I should embed the log message creation logic inside strings in a static array and then `eval()` those strings, which doesn't seem like an elegant solution to me.

Comment: Can you not store the array then use something like `sprintf` to input the values rather than `eval`? That's a little cleaner.

Comment: I would still need to create lots of functions that use sprintf() to create the log message, just use %s instead of concatenation

Comment: You can replace third param with log string: `public function signUpSuccessful($event, $source, 'log message here')`. And then: `$this->logger->log(Logger::info, $third_param);`

Comment: Yeah, but then what's the point of using events? I could just create a `UserServiceLogger` class that just takes a string argument and logs it. However, I'm trying not to clutter up my business logic with sprintf() and log-message-construction logic.