# How to return from a function using eval?

Tags: php

I have a function which is basically like this:

```
function myfunction(){
    eval("return;");
    echo 'this line has to not show up';
}
```

For technical reasons, the decision to return (or not) from the function, has to be made in the eval instruction, but the above approach doesn't work. How can I make this work?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672183/eval-does-not-return-the-function-results If you must must use `eval` then eval the entire function: https://eval.in/315419 I'm guessing though that there's much better options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The contents of the `eval` are considered their own context, so "return" is interpreted as exiting the eval'd string, and returning control to the function. A few alternatives to consider:

- Return a value from the eval string determining the action to take, e.g. `if ( eval('return true;') ) { return; }`
- Throw an Exception inside the eval'd string, and catch it wherever you call this function.
- **Don't use eval in the first place**. There is pretty much always a better approach than using eval. Without knowing what you're using this code for, I can't be more specific, but I would strongly recommend changing your design rather than continuing down this route.