# Eval alternatives for array creation

Tags: php, eval

I am storing an array in string form in a database for later retrieval: 
The value of the array happens to be parameters for a [filter_val](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) call.

```
$str = 'array("options" => array("min_range" => 4))';
```

I know I can use

```
eval('$options = ' . $str . ';');
```

to prepare this value for passing to filter_val, but is there any other way to do this?

[This related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671602/whats-alternative-of-eval-function) (while excellent) didn't handle my exact issue.

Comment: Store it as a `json_encode` string?

Comment: Yeah, if you're going to take it outside the realm of your code then just store it in a way that keeps the information of the array but without the concept of the data structure, which you can easily recreate. I would vote for JSON as well.

Comment: Recommend JSON myself, as it's more portable than using `serialize`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not use `eval()` to get your string functional. For example, the function `eval` [may be disallowed on some hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865020/php-how-to-disable-dangerous-functions), thus your application will not work.

A more appropriate way would be to store your options in a [`json_encode()`'d](http://php.net/json_encode) string, and decode when you need.

```
$options = json_decode($options_from_db);
```

Or as [John Conde mentions, you can serialise it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037133/eval-alternatives-for-array-creation/29037200#comment46314948_29037133).

Comment: For some reason, I was resistant to doing this until I realized it would work like a charm. :)