# How to pass string into if condition statement in php?

Tags: php, eval

I have stored conditions in database string format. ex: `((25>1)||(25<1))` How can I pass this string to `if` condition statement. I tried, but it's not working. I have used `eval()` function, but it's not working.

```
$con=eval("return ((25>1)||(25<1))");
if($con){
    echo "success";
}
else{
    echo "failed";
}
```

Comment: _Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting '**;**' : eval()'d code on line 1_

Comment: `$con=eval("return ((25>1)||(25<1));");` http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/55f1b71dba75a8af7427cf396a3c06bb96fe98a6

Comment: @AbraCadaver sorry i forgot to add semicolon inside of eval
<?php $con=eval("return ((25>1)||(25<1));");
if($con){
    echo "success";
 }
 else{
    echo "failed";
 }
 ?>

Comment: @AbraCadaver my doubt instead of eval any alternative is their?

Comment: You didn't ask for an alternative you said _i have use eval() function but not working_ Without writing your own parser I don't know of an alternative.

Comment: If you have a database you might be able to `SELECT  ((25>1)||(25<1)) AS result`

Comment: @AbraCadaver Okay thanks!. if it's string working but mine saved as json

Comment: OK, then decode it.  You keep commenting things that should be in your question.

Comment: Okay Thanks @AbraCadaver

Answer (score 1):

**You can do like this as well:**

```
echo (25 > 1 ? "success" : ( 25 < 1 ? "success" : "failed")) ;
```

Comment: this conditional statement okay. but my question is how to convert string ex: ((25>1)||(25<1)) this directly pass to if condition, i tried now eval worked but most of say eval is not safe so i try finding any other alternative, do you know something alternative for this?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a semicolon in your `eval()`. Strings passed into `eval()` still must be  valid PHP, which will need an `;`.

```
$con = eval('return ((25>1)||(25<1));');
if($con) {
    echo 'success';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

Comment: This working thanks!. is that any alternate for eval?

Comment: Why would you need an alternative?

Comment: because i searched most of say don't use eval .

Comment: I've found some different ways to do it from this post, is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/17700065/5066625

Comment: Using eval isn´t a good thing, but as long as there is no (un-validated) user input, it´s fine security wise.