# replace eval function to run old code at php

Tags: php

I have a web / app based on phpbb version 1 and I need to migrate the function

```
eval ($ this-> compiled_code [$ handle]);
```

but I don't see alternatives, is it possible?

Comment: Maybe: https://www.google.com/url?q=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671602/whats-alternative-of-eval-function&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwi6yqmAhe_xAhX13zgGHYonAPYQFjAAegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw3-MxwQrPu_a6yc3WO5LM48

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? As `eval` has not been deprecated or removed after all, why do you need to change anything?

Comment: Version 1.0 from 2000? First, congrats for having code that lives that long, working and untouched for 20+ years, I don’t think my brain could work in PHP 4 anymore! If nothing is broken, I agree, don’t try to fix it!